# executing tracking script on external link out

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink, analytics, tracking

I am curious on the best way to execute a database query and set a cookie when a user clicks an external link, without having that script passed to the browser history so when the user goes back from the external site they will land on the same page they clicked the link and not the page that executes the tracking script.

I noticed google tracks on an external click, not sure how but I see there is a mousedown event that possibly changes the href location of the link to their tracking script?

How can I achieve a similar function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for tracking clicks I posted earlier today:

[counter for number of clicks on links in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221409/counter-for-number-of-clicks-on-links-in-php/5221645#5221645)

Comment: I got the script working but I cannot get it to set a cookie. Any idea?

Comment: You mean set a cookie when doing the tracking? You can't do that with an Image request (like the one the script uses) as far as I know. If you set a session cookie when you first load the page, you should be able to act on that session information in the tracking script, though.

Comment: I want to store an id in a cookie to prevent duplicate clicks which can affect the accuracy of analytics. Im thinking that setting the cookie via js is the way to go?